# Sending callbacks to dialog box modal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a reusable library for a GUI system where I want to send callbacks to a static method which displays a dialog box modal. Pseudo-ish, I want to do something like this:

```cs
void OnQuitButtonClick()
{
    var buttons = new OrderedDictionary();
    buttons.Add( "OK", (Action)(() => { Debug.Log("OK was pressed!"); }) );
    buttons.Add( "Cancel", (Action)(() => { Debug.Log("Cancel was pressed!"); }) );

    DialogBox.Show(
        "Do you really want to quit?",
        buttons
    );
}
```

Then, in the DialogBox class:

```cs
public static Show(string message, OrderedDictionary buttons)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in buttons)
    {
        var button = ...; // Instantiate the button object here.
        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener( () => { de.Value; Close(); } );
    }
}

void Close()
{
    Destroy(gameObject); // Destroys "self".
}
```

This doesn't work, but it's all I've managed to google/read my way to, and I have the feeling that I'm pretty close.

Any ideas on how to progress, and maybe make it a bit prettier, will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually executing your button handler code. You probably want to change this

```cs
button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener( () => { de.Value; Close(); } );
```

to this

```cs
button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener( () => {
    ((Action)de.Value).Invoke();
    Close();
});
```